# How to check for missing partials

Tags: openmdao

I implemented a system that is composed of few groups and multiple components. It is relatively intricate and has component inputs/outputs, which some partials are dependent/non dependent etc.

Gradient based optimizers seem to get stuck at the initial values and never go further than iteration 0 (not stuck at local optimum). I have encountered this error before as I was missing declare_partials for some variables. Is there a way to automatically check which component input/output is missing partials similar to missing connection in N^2 diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tools that you need to use to check for bad derivatives. The first is [check_partials](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/advanced_guide/derivs/partial_derivs_explicit.html). That will go component by component and use either finite-difference or complex-step to verify the partial derivatives for every component (regardless of whether or not your declared them in the setup of that component). That will catch the problem if you are missing any partials, because the check-fd will see them as non-zero and will show you that there is an error.

Check_partials should be your first stop, always. If you can, use complex-step to verify your derivatives. That way you know they are totally accurate. Also, check_partials will do the check around whatever point is currently initialized. So sometimes you might have a degenerate case (e.g. you have some input that is 0) and so your check_passes, but your derivatives are still wrong. For example, if your component represented y=2*x, and you forgot to define derivatives, but you ran check_partials at x=0, then the check would pass.  But if you ran it at x=1, then the check would show an error.

If all of your partial derivatives are correct, but you're still getting bad results then you can try [check_totals](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/check_total_derivatives.html). Depending on the structure of your model, and if you have any coupling in it (i.e. you need to use some kind of nonlinear solver) then its possible that you don't have a correctly configured linear solver setup to solve for total derivatives correctly. In a lot of cases, if you have coupling you can just put a [DirectSolver](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/linear/direct_solver.html) right at the same level as the nonlinear solver you put in the model.